# Terraform deploying 3 nodes regardless of mentioned node count 1

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have written the following script to that should keep 1 node in default and another node in a second pool. It has started 3 nodes in each pool. Also the remove default_node_pool = true didn't work.

Version:
Terraform v1.1.1
on darwin_amd64

- provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google v4.61.0

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "chess-cluster-london" {
  name               = "chess-cluster-london"
  location           = "europe-west1"
  initial_node_count = 1
  resource_labels    = {}
  remove_default_node_pool = true

  node_config {
    resource_labels = {}
    tags            = []
    machine_type    = "e2-standard-4"
    disk_size_gb    = 100

    oauth_scopes = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
    ]
  }
}

resource "google_container_node_pool" "chess-node-pool" {
  name       = "chess-node-pool"
  location   = "europe-west1"
  cluster    = google_container_cluster.chess-cluster-london.name
  node_count = 1

  node_config {
    machine_type = "e2-standard-4"
    disk_size_gb = 100
    oauth_scopes = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Terraform Doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_cluster#location), if we use Region then default nodes will be set into each Zone under these Region.  In your Terraform script, can you change location from Region  **"europe-west1"** to **Zone europe-west1-b**.

> location - (Optional) The location (region or zone) in which the
> cluster master will be created, as well as the default node location.
> If you specify a zone (such as us-central1-a), the cluster will be a
> zonal cluster with a single cluster master. If you specify a region
> (such as us-west1), the cluster will be a regional cluster with
> multiple masters spread across zones in the region, and with default
> node locations in those zones as well

You can also refer to this terraform official doc example for [2 node pools one is default and the other is separately managed](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_node_pool#example-usage---2-node-pools-1-separately-managed--the-default-node-pool). Try by following this doc and changing the location from region to zone and let us know any errors you are facing.

Comment: Please let me know whether the shared info was helpful and the issue resolved?. I am happy to assist if you have any further queries.

Comment: make sense now, thanks.